# Why use an ARMA process theory instead of just performing linear regression?

Tags: time-series, moving-average, autoregressive-model, linear-prediction

I am studying ARMA processes. At the end of the course the professor told us that estimating the next sample in an arma process using past of length $p$ (so performing a projection of $X_t$ on $\text{span}(X_{t-1}, ..., X_{t-1-p})$ is the same as finding the least squares solution to $X_t = aX_{t-1} + bX_{t-2}...$, which can be just done by accumulating the "samples" as a moving window of length $p$, the prediction length, over the whole signal and then using any way to solve linear regression problems.

My question then is: why do we need the complicated theory of ARMA processes, and solutions involving covariance matrices etc, which are way more complicated to find, when we can just perform a simple linear regression? What's more, a linear regression can simply be extended to a polynomial (or kernel) regression, a model much more powerful than a linear model basically for free, giving a more powerful model than just an ARMA process.

It feels like from a practical perspective, ARMA model is just a complicated way of saying "linear regression on previous samples". Am I missing something? There surely must be an explanation of why we do all of this computation.

Answer (score 2):

I know it’s been a while since you asked the question, but I figured I’d give it a shot. AR/MA/ARMA models are a statistical tool in the analysis of time series. They are used for modeling Wide Sense Stationary stochastic processes, and as such they are not just a linear combination of previous values. They assume that the model is driven by white noise.

The MA model is a linear combination of previous error terms *plus a stochastic term*, and the AR model says that the current value is a linear combination of previous values *plus a stochastic term*. This is the key difference. General linear regression is not statistical in nature whereas ARMA models are. Due to their stochastic nature, they provide optimal regression coefficients of *random processes*, under certain assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ARMA models are not just simple linear regression.

If we have

$$
Y_t = a_1X_{t-1} + a_2X_{t-2}\cdots + a_p X_{t-p} + \epsilon_t
$$

then this is simply a moving average (MA) model.

To get an ARMA model one needs to also include past outputs, the auto-regressive (AR) part of the idea:

$$
Y_t =  a_1X_{t-1} + a_2X_{t-2}\cdots + a_p X_{t-p} \color{blue}{+ 
 b_1 Y_{t-1} + b_2 Y_{t-2} + \cdots b_q Y_{t-p}} 
$$

which, given the recursive relationship between $Y_t$ and its past values, is not amenable to simple linear regression.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is for a MA process, however ARMA processes are much more powerful than that. But combining the modelling ability of poles and zeros you are able to have a parametric representation of the process and/or its spectrum. For example complex conjugate pole pais you are able to accurately describe spectral peaks.